# What's the difference between AlertDialog.builder.setView and Dialog.setContentView?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

Here are the docs:

[AlertDialog.builder.setView](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29) **: Set a custom view to be the contents of the Dialog.**

[Dialog.setContentView](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29) **: Set the screen content to an explicit view.**

But i am still a little confused, could anybody explain them in more details?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.SavedState.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setView` does just that...sets one `View`. So it could be a `ListView`, `TextView`, etc...

`setContentView` is just like when you set it for an `Activity`. It sets a complete `layout`. Depending on which `setContentView` you use it may be a parent `layout` or a layout inflated from xml

`setContentView(View view)`

> Set the screen content to an explicit view. This view is placed directly into the screen's view hierarchy. It can itself be a complex view hierarhcy.

or

`setContentView(int layoutResID)`

> Set the screen content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the screen.

Comment: It's much more clear now. Thanks for the explanation.